# Html.ActionLink URL error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, view, html.actionlink

```
return RedirecttoAction("Success")
```

how to generate redirection?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong overload of [Html.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505070.aspx), you need

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("linkText", "actionName", "controllerName") %>
```

Without the third `controllerName` parameter it will default to the current controller which appears to be in this case your UserController when I expect you want to direct to the AccountController.  That is why the `ActionLink` works in your other view.

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the controller name for the controller that contains your `login` action method.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. ActionLink renders a link to a URL based on the actionName and controllerName you specify. If you want your users to be able to navigation to your `Login` action in your `AccountController` then you spcifiy `Html.ActionLink("log me in", "Login", "Account")` and this will generally render `<a href="/Account/Login">log me in</a>`

Comment: If you don't have an action method called `contact` then where do you want URL to navigate to? Why can't you just use plain HTML?

Comment: If you have no `Contact` action method then MVC will not know how to service the requested URL. Can you post you full controller and view code in order for anyone to help you further?